YouTube channel name changes at morning to the name and then displays name with date and changes intermittently to the name
My name changes at morning to the name, then displays name with date and changes at night intermittently to the name.
Changing at morning to the name
Changing at night intermittently to the name
The black profile picture will appear at morning, but I don't see confused about my name.
Then I appear now at night to the name, but works perfectly.
What's wrong about my date?
My date is 31 December 1969, likely than Android system date. Please fix it at the settings app, then sets the date, and you can now display the current date.
Thanks!

How is this a programming question?
